# Display STL Classes in DDD

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, gdb

I am writing a c++ compiler, and using g++ to compile my source and gdb as a debugger. I have used STL classes like list, vector too much. I started using DDD as a GUI for gdb. But it  doesn't show me the stl classes properly. Could anyone suggest me how to display stl contents neatly in DDD?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610906/debugging-c-code-with-templates-and-stl-with-gdb

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: I am able to use the command line debugger and get a pretty print using a .gdbinit file. But I am unable to get the same in DDD.

Comment: @Chethan Ravindranath: in this case the title of your question is misleading. The title claims a problem with GDB, while the question and your comment claim there is none for GDB, but instead for DDD.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that! Edited the title to not mislead...

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt) file as your .gdbinit and you should be all set since the DDD is only a frontend of gdb.

Comment: I had used the same init file before, and the command line gdb works fine with that, but DDD doesn't seem to do a pretty print using this file.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you write for example "pvector vec" in the ddd command line it prints the values exactly as it should.

Comment: Yep. pvector and plist work fine, but ddd has an option called display, where when you double click on the a pointer, it display the value pointed by the pointer. Likewise, when I double click on a vector variable, it shows the vector but not in a neat way.

Comment: Just change your debugger if you want more than you have. There are a lot of better gdb frontends. KDevelop has nice gdb integration, CodeLite has it too, the list continues.

Comment: Wish you pleasant coding using KDevelop :).

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> GDB Settings...
Enable Prettyprinting of structures

Answer (score 0):

1. follow the [stl-views](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport)tips,make the gdb can display stls;
2. delete the ddd's init file in '~/.ddd/init' and open ddd again,enjoy it!