# How to install gdb stl support

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I have seen a solution without .gdbinit

it seems it has this extra file

```
/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/__init__.py
```

when installed it look like this

```
(gdb) p m
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {[1] = 2, [2] = 4}
```

Comment: Hope it will help u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610906/debugging-c-code-with-templates-and-stl-with-gdb

Answer (score 1):

I was going into following document and found following thing.

> Add the following to your ~/.gdbinit. The path needs to match where
>   the python module above was checked-out. So if checked out to:
>   /home/maude/gdb_printers/, the path would be as written in the
>   example

http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: I found a system that there is no .gdbinit  
I don't how it is installed .

Comment: There obviously a easy way to do that,  but I don't know how